# Create and format Date in Angular template

Tags: angular

Why can't I do this in angular:

```
<p>Copyright {{ new Date() }}</p>
```

If I bind it to a variable then it works of course.

But for something so simple, isn't there a way to do so without a binding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained by @Bjorn'Bjeaurn'S in the comments

> You don't have access to the JavaScript API from within the scoped HTML.

So the binding is necessary.

Answer (score 4):

you can pipe it. Do the binding and then:

```
<p>Copyright {{ myDateInsideTheComponent | date: 'yyyy' }}</p>
```

notice how everything after the `| date:` is a date format of your choosing. Happy coding!

Comment: Quick heads up; if your app gets slow over time, it may be because the `DatePipe` (used to be?!) is not a `pure` function, which means it recalculates itself and is not necessarily very efficient. If this becomes a problem (not only with the `DatePipe`), calculate once upon retrieval and show directly. :-)

Comment: Thanks... but what I want to know is whether I can avoid a binding?

Comment: @Bjorn'Bjeaurn'S What do you mean "once upon retrieval", you mean calculate it in the constructor/etc.?

Comment: Not in the constructor, upon retrieval is basically where your data comes from. If you're working the "Angular way", you may be using the `HttpClient` or RxJS' `Observables` throughout the system. You can `map()` over your values and set it's new calculated value inside the object, without your HTML or component knowing about it.

Comment: But the `DatePipe` is still a solid way to go. My experiences after showing 25.000 rows that used a few pipes are somewhat extreme and led us to optimize for that situation. This is over 2 years ago, so I'm sure the `DatePipe` has seen some optimization of its own.

Comment: @Bjorn'Bjeaurn'S Oh okay, generally I understand what you mean, but in this specific case for showing a "copyright 2019" text the data is just calculated inline. :) I am surprised angular won't allow me to do that without a binding, seems overkill.

Comment: You don't have access to the JavaScript API from within the scoped HTML.

Comment: @Bjorn'Bjeaurn'S Aha! Now that makes sense. Actually that's the answer - if you add it, I'll accept. Thanks.